# Has Per Degaton appeared in any of the current DC comics adaptations?

Tags: dc, the-flash-2014, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In the first episode of *Legends of Tomorrow*, Rip Hunter mentions three despots: Caesar, Hitler, and Per Degaton. I haven't watched *Arrow*, but I do watch *The Flash* and *Supergirl*. The mention of someone who hasn't appeared yet strikes me as unusual - unlike the MCU, DC's adaptations seem positively loath to mention anyone who's not directly involved in the adaptation's plot. Per Degaton, [Wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Degaton), is a time-travelling supervillain.

Is Per Degaton slated to appear in *Legends of Tomorrow*, or in *Arrow*, or in *The Flash*, or has he appeared already?

---

> A young Per Degaton does appear in episode 10, *Progeny*. And, it seems, in *Legends of Tomorrow*, Per Degaton is just a patsy for Vandal Savage, wiping out much of the world's population, thus preparing the world for conquest by Savage.

Comment: arrow has made mention of ferris air and bludhaven. they're not completely adverse to making references that have had no other connection to the plot.

Comment: @phantom42 indirect references, yes. Outright mentions? I have yet to see any.

Comment: [bludhaven has been name dropped a few times](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Bl%C3%BCdhaven), and not only has ferris air been mentioned by name, [the logo has shown up](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2932327).

Comment: @phantom42 agreed, but has either Hal Jordan or Green Lantern been mentioned by name?

Comment: not yet, but my point is that they're completely fine dropping easter eggs that may or may not pay off later.

Comment: @phantom42 And my point is that them mentioning an uninvolved character *by name* is very out of character. If they'd mentioned time clones or something, it would be in line with indirectly referencing Green Lantern by his city and the company he works for.

Comment: Hal Jordan was the name on a flying jacket hung up in a bar in an episode of Arrow.

Comment: @user23614 something I'd missed. That is big. Yet, note, nobody says they had a beer with their buddy Hal Jordan last night.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having seen every episode of *Arrow*, *Flash*, and *Legends of Tomorrow*, I can say that Per Degaton has not shown up in any of those yet.  MikeEdenfield confirms in a comment that he doesn't show up in the *Arrow: Season 2.5* comic book or in S1 of *Vixen*.

However, I have not read the <strike>Arrow: Season 2.5 or</strike> *Flash: Season Zero* comic books, so I don't know if he's shown up there.

Comment: no mention of him in *Arrow Season 2.5* or *Vixen*. Also, FWIW, the Arrowverse Wiki only lists him as "mentioned in *Legends of Tomorrow*"

Answer (score 2):

A new episode of Legends of Tomorrow recently came out talking about Per Degaton. He came to power and killed many people during his reign and he was betrayed by Vandall Savage. This ultimately led to Savage's rise to power. Per Degaton was mentioned with Ceaser and Hitler because they are all ruthless, genocidal maniacs.